# UITextChecker and non english words

Tags: ios, spell-checking, custom-keyboard, non-ascii-characters, uitextchecker

I'm developing a custom keyboard for the iOS operating system and I'm trying to add the auto-suggestion feature. For English dictionary there seems to be no difficulties, but for languages like french I came into a problem regarding accents. See this example: The user tries to write "Chaîne" (chain). the `UITextChecker` retrieves words until user reaches the "î", after that the it stops, the word list is empty.

The code to retrieve the word list is as follow:

```
    // While user is typing the txt variable is modified...
    range = NSMakeRange(0, txt.length);
    words = [m_textChecker completionsForPartialWordRange:range inString:txt language:@"fr_FR"];
```

This problem happens also using Italian and other languages that use accented letters. You do not retrieve "città" (city) while typing "cit..." or "citt..."

Maybe it is my fault in understanding the `completionsForPartialWordRange:inString:language` method real meaning.

I tried to choose other solutions, for example including an SQLite database importing the Aspell dictionaries, but I'm not sure if it is legal and it will be accepted by Apple review team. Moreover database originating from Aspell are quite big. To solve the latter issue I though to use an optional download feature from the containing app, but I can't figure out how its keyboard extension could access the app's `Documents' folder, because they do not share the same bundle path for that folder.

Can any one help me in understanding the `UITextChecker` and accented words?

Thank you very much...